# Efficiently index into a Multi-index dataframe (with default handling)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, optimization, vectorization

I've been charged with optimizing an API and when I run my profiler I see that 70% of the cumulative run time is taken by the functionality described below. It would be great if you could point me toward resources that could help me make this faster.
It would be amazing if I could make this a vector operation but I'm drawing blanks

Due to product requirements, I have to query lm_df twice per API call. Optimizing this would be amazing.

I have a multi-index df as follows:

*lm_df*

|  |  |  | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **X** | **Y** | **Z** |  |
| x1 | y1 | z1 | 1.2 |
| x1 | not_available | z1 | 1.3 |
| x1 | not_available | not_available | 1.36 |
| not_available | y1 | z2 | 1.31 |
| not_available | y2 | z2 | 1.32 |
| not_available | not_available | z2 | 1.33 |
| not_available | y1 | not_available | 1.34 |
| not_available | y2 | not_available | 1.5 |
| not_available | not_available | not_available | 1.37 |
| x3 | y3 | z1 | 1.9 |
| x3 | y3 | not_available | 3.4 |
| x3 | not_available | not_available | 5.7 |

*note*: X, Y and Z are in a multi-index and are categorical values. In real word data, I have 6 features, and the last feature contains more than 200 unique values.
As you go deeper every level, it will contain a "not_available" feature. This feature is to be used if your category is not supported for the current index.
For example: X1 does not support y2, if the client request for (X1, Y2, Z1), we should use (X1, not_available, Z1) to index into lm_df and return 1.3

I need to index into lm_df based on the client's request:

This is the code I'm currently using that is slow:

```
def assign_prediction_feature(feat, model, row):
    current_feat = getattr(row, feat)
    return (
        current_feat
        if current_feat in model.index.get_level_values(feat)
        else "not_available"
    )

def problem_function(row, model):
    x_index = assign_prediction_feature("X", model, row)
    x_model =  model.loc[x_index]

    y_index = assign_prediction_feature("Y", x_model, row)
    y_model =  x_model.loc[y_index]

    z_index = assign_prediction_feature("Z", y_model, row)
    value =  y_model.loc[z_index].value
    return value

df["value"] = df.apply(
            problem_function,
            models=lm_df,
            axis=1,
        )
```

According to the profiler, a large portion of the time is taken by indexing.
*note*: This is for two calls to problem_function
[image]

Comment: I've been trying to recreate that profile with https://github.com/nschloe/tuna , but it looks very different. Which profiler did you use?

Comment: This profile is made by snakeviz and cProfile. It is profiling my entire API, of which this functionality is a small part